# mysql similar search query results

Tags: php, mysql, search

I need to know how to display similar search query usernames like if there is a user names : johnhol , _john_ , donjohnqq , king_john , code_john
and if we search john then all names starting from john must display currently iam using

```
$result = mysql_Query("SELECT user FROM UserData WHERE user LIKE '%$username%'") or die(mysql_error());
$fetch = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

but it's not displaying like what i told it's Displaying only some names like _john_ , king_john like names only displaying as per the code so please tell me how to search with search query and display all starting names in the mysql database.

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will fit into your exact idea, but try looking into MySQL's [`SOUNDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_soundex)

Comment: What names exactly is it *not* listing? Show some examples.

Comment: if i type john_glen and it's not displaying john_glenn

Answer (score 0):

I *THINK* you are looking for everything which starts with `$username`. Is that correct? If so, then your query should only have one `%` at the end:

```
SELECT user FROM UserData WHERE user LIKE '$username%'
```

That will match `john_glenn` but not `glenn_johnson`.